# how to upload a Map of files to php server

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to send multiple files attached to a post to a Laravel backend. They should all be in a field named `media` which is an array which maps filetype to the actual file. Here is a representation of what backend expects:

```php
'media' => [
    'image' => UploadedFile,
    'video' => UploadedFile,
    'music' => UploadedFile,
   // other type of files
]
```

I've tried many solutions from the Internet. If I use `@Query` annotation backend receives the structure right, but files are not being received as expected. If I use `@Part` annotation, I cannot send a named array (i.e. `media`).

Comment: Use Multipart anotation....

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself through trial and error.

Here is the corresponding method in my route interface:

```java
@Multipart
@POST("posts")
Call<ResponseBody> createPost(
    @Part ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> files
    //other parameters
);
```

Whenever in your code that you are packing data for sending, initialize an `ArrayList` and add files like the following:

```java
RequestBody reqFile;

reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), file);

ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> partArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
partArrayList.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("media[image]",file.getName(),reqFile));
partArrayList.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("media[video]",file.getName(),reqFile));

route.createPost(
    partArrayList
    /*other_parameters*/
);
```